# Wifi connection unstable Ubuntu 14.04.3 with RTL8188CUS USB dongle

Tags: wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

Acer Power F5 PC and wifi usb dongle. Connection crashes all the time. Any solution?

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Please remove this comment and post it TO YOUR QUESTION. It is unreadable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect to internet by wire and run in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms
```

reboot and test the dongle.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rtl8192cu-dkms

Comment: Are you connected to internet?

Comment: at the moment yes, get full package, same answer

Comment: Did you press Enter on first command? I updated to make it easier a bit. Try again. There was a typo. I fixed it @TarmoMultanen

Comment: tarmo@tarmo-AcerPower-F5:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rlwifi
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:hanipouspilot/rlwifi'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

Comment: I fixed it, sry. It is `rtlwifi`

Comment: Seems that wifi is OK now. Thanks a lot for ur assistance :-)

Comment: @TarmoMultanen Please accept the answer by clicking the check sign at the left to show that it works.